# Synchronization in booking reservation application

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, dao, synchronized

I have a very fundamental doubt about synchronization vis-a-vis the classic Servlet -> Service -> DAO pattern.

Let's say I have a ticket booking application that is accessed by several concurrent users. No two users should end up booking the same ticket. When two different users try to access the ticket booking, I think the following happens -

- the web container creates request/response objects for the two
  requests. Maps the request url to a servlet (let's say, BookingServlet).
- creates threads for each request in order to run the service method
  of the BookingServlet.
- the service -> doPost method creates a BookingService object and passes the seat information.
- BookingService object does some business logic and instantiates the
  BookingDAO object to connect with DB and do the updates.

Now, in order to avoid two users booking the same ticket where must the synchronization happen?

Is it at the BookingService or at the BookingDAO?

But then, and this is my doubt, for each request we are essentially creating a separate BookingService and BookingDAO objects - wouldn't that defeat the purpose of putting synchronized in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unique Identifier**

A relatively simple solution could be use the [Java UUID](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56). We used this method, in a project in order to ensure people could not create the same `lobby` at the same time.

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class GenerateUUID {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    //generate random UUIDs
    UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID idTwo = UUID.randomUUID();
    log("UUID One: " + idOne);
    log("UUID Two: " + idTwo);
  }

  private static void log(Object aObject){
    System.out.println( String.valueOf(aObject) );
  }
}
```

Additionally, if you wanted to reduce the likelihood of one user getting the same `UUID` as another user. You could concatenate the `Primary Key` of the user, to the end of the **UUID**.

For example `067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00` becomes `067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00-23`, Given every user contains a different `Primary Key` the probability, of two users hitting the same `Token` is very low.

> 1. Create a unique session ID, e.g. `UUID sessionID = UUID.randomUUID();`
> 2. Begin transaction
> 3. Delete any tokens from the DB that match the one in the request, e.g.
>      DELETE FROM Tokens WHERE TokenID = *<requested-token>*
> 4. Get the affected row count
> 5. If the affected row count is exactly 1, then the token was valid.  Create a session, e.g.
>      INSERT INTO Session VALUES (sessionUUID, userID, loginTime, ...)
> 6. Commit transaction

[source: finnw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12048/finnw), [java: race conditions - is there a way to make sure several lines of code will be executed together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222175/java-race-conditions-is-there-a-way-to-make-sure-several-lines-of-code-will-b)

**Mutual Exclusion**

Otherwise I believe, you need will need develop something that has mutual exclusion so that both parties (people booking a ticket, cannot book the same ticket at the same time). Look at [Lamport's bakery algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport's_bakery_algorithm)

> Lamport envisioned a bakery with a numbering machine at its entrance so each customer is given a unique number. Numbers increase by one as customers enter the store. A global counter displays the number of the customer that is currently being served. All other customers must wait in a queue until the baker finishes serving the current customer and the next number is displayed. When the customer is done shopping and has disposed of his or her number, the clerk increments the number, allowing the next customer to be served. That customer must draw another number from the numbering machine in order to shop again.

For example using `static LinkedList` to keep track of every Ticket number ordered today.

Comment: Thanks, but can elaborate how generating unique ids would help in synchronization concurrent booking. Do we need to generate an id for each request and store it in the DB against the seat number that was requested, and then perform the operations by matching the id?

Comment: You could generate an ID then store data regarding a booking within a java Object, once the booking is confirmed.. then move said data to the Database. Using a UUID ensures no one misses out, and you don't have any race conditions. Using singular or double digit integers, if you base your booking system using 0-100; you will probably have a race condition at one point or another.

Comment: [Failure Resilient Distributed Commit for Web Services Atomic Transactions](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228573042_Failure_Resilient_Distributed_Commit_for_Web_Services_Atomic_Transactions) is a good system that uses UUID (`Universal Unique Identifier`).

Comment: Ok, I have a question. Please bear with me. Two users try to book the same seat. Two requests comes in. Since two requests are processed in separate threads by the servlet, they end up creating individual service/dao objects. Wouldn't they in turn create their own UUIDs? How would I consider which UUID is the one to associate with the seat?

Comment: If you use a `static` variable the data will be usable within both threads. Look at [this project](http://se-projects.massey.ac.nz/ttt3/), open two browsers (IE and Chrome); create a lobby and you'll understand, that static data is viewable from both browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways how to tackle your problem.

1. make `BookingService` and/or `BookingDAO` singleton. Usually there is no need to have more instances. Then you can do synchronization. Or you can make synchronization on class. eg. `synchronized(BookingService.class)`.

This approach works only if you have only one instance of application running. Therefore I would recommend second option (assuming you are using relational DB)

2. Use your DB to do "synchronization". Assuming that you have "unreserved" ticket for each seat on place in your DB and you want to be able to reserve it for user or undo this if the order was cancelled (or not paid within given time). Then you can use "optimistic" approach to do reservation (pseudo SQL): `update ticket set reserved_by = 'CustomerA' where ticket_id = 23 and reserved_by = null` After the update you need to check the number of updated rows. If it is `1`, everything is okey, if it is `0`, it means that ticket was in-between reserved by someone else and customer needs to make new reservation.

Comment: I'm not really sure I would recommend this, in Java ... you need to be conservative when you use the database, every request that is made.. is an  expense on the server (every pull, request is expensive; because of the inner workings of connection pools). Therefore basing your entire synchronization strategy on your database doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: in this particular case I see this as very suitable solution. First DB are built for concurrency and connection pools make DB requests more effective. But mainly in this situation you want to update DB to make reservation anyway thus you **don't do any extra work in good case** (i.e. there is no collision). I assume that risk of collision is reasonable low - but that's traditional trade-off between pessimistic and optimistic locking.

Comment: Yeah I agree that databases are built are built for concurrency, as every request is ATOMIC. My comment, is regarding scale, if you have 3000 people ordering tickets within the same time period, your database may have some conflicting transactions ("All or Nothing" synchronization). But in saying this, I don't think you can avoid using the database with linear synchronization regardless. I personally, think the database should only be used at the very end, when the data is going to be committed (and not before).

Comment: @Killrawr Thanks. I was thinking along the same lines. I'm using spring to inject the dao and service. If they are singleton scoped, then i guess i can have the synchronized version of the booking method. My doubt is whether this is the best practice or are there more elegant ways of tackling this usecase. The optimistic locking would be the last ditch effort if nothing else works.

Comment: @The_301 see my answer, regarding UUID (and ID concatenation, which would create a unique ID for every booking). [Good case study on UUID](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.nz/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html)